# How to define HTML templates with QGIS Server?

Tags: mapserver, popup, getfeatureinfo, qgis-server

I usually use HTML templates in map files to show nicely formatted popups on my WMS layers with Openlayers. [Here is the doc on templating with mapserver](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html#template)

I'd like to know if it is possible to do the same in GQIS Server and if yes how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new functionality in QGIS Desktop > 1.8 (you need to download the master).
You can add a HTML map tip or just choose one of the field to display.

I also installed the nightly build of QGIS Server on my ubuntu server and I set "useGetProjectSettings" to true in GlobalOption.js in QGIS Web Client.

I now can see the value of a chosen field in QGIS Web Client but HTML display doesn't work.
I found that it will be implemented in a future release : http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Label-with-HTML-expressions-tp5042897p5064207.html

I also found another way to get HTML template here : http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8370 but you need to define your HTML in GlobalOption.js and it has not been commited yet.

Comment: Both the links are dead, could you please add the relevant information right in your answer?